# How to populate an HTML table with JSON array values in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array as below:

```
var publicArray={
"settings": [{
"id": "1",
"deleted": "0",
"data": [{
"title": " Business Unit",
"value": "B1"
},
{
"title": "Comp ",
"value": "C1"
},
{
"title": " Pa Id",
"value": "P1"
}, {
"title": " NPI",
"value": "4535"
}
]
}, {
"id": "2",
"deleted": "0",
"data": [{
"title": " Business Unit",
"value": "B2"
},
{
"title": "Comp ",
"value": "C2"
},
{
"title": " Pa Id",
"value": "P2"
}, {
"title": " NPI",
"value": "34242"
}
]
}]
};
```

The array comes actually from a database, so it may extend, that means, that more rows will come as the array grows.

I need to populate an HTML table using this array as follow image[image: this is how the table looks like].

I am new to this, please help me to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having component's property called `publicArray` you can you can achive that by writing the following template:

```
<table *ngIf="publicArray?.settings?.length && publicArray.settings[0].data?.length">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th *ngFor="let header of publicArray.settings[0].data">{{ header.title }}</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let row of publicArray.settings">
    <td>{{ row.id }}</td>
    <td *ngFor="let col of row.data">
      {{ col.value }}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/BpibKjA5emypKHE6rckv?open=app%2Fapp.component.html)**

Answer (score 1):

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Business Unit</th>
    <th>Comp</th>
    <th>Pa Id</th>
    <th>NPI</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of data.settings; let i=index">
      <td>{{item.id}}</td>
      <td *ngFor="let item2 of item.data">{{item2.value}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jbtmyt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

[image: preview]

Answer (score 0):

There are many libraries that you can use to create a table, like [PrimeNG](https://primeng.org/), [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/), etc.

I'll give you this example of "ngx smart table":
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-smart-table.

You can follow the documentation:

- By setting the `settings{}` object, you'll define your table header.
- Then define another object from your brought data `publicArray`,  so that it can match the same names as in the `settings{}`.